# Quickly User Dialog error

Tags: python, quickly, pygtk

I think there is an error in the Quickly tutorial. In the User Dialog section, the tutorial instructs users to enter:
title = saver.title_text
in the save dialog method. This gives some error which is fixed by using:
title = save.title_text()

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/quickly/+filebug

Comment: @RobinJ Actually, it's better to report bugs with `ubuntu-bug`, which includes important technical information automatically (pertaining to version, Ubuntu release, and app configuration). See the [bug reporting documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs) for details. Furthermore, when reporting bugs, it's advisable to search first to see if it's already been reported, rather than starting out by filling out a new report.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error, you just need to add **@property** to the line above the title_txt method. So, your code should look like this:

```
@property
def title_text(self):
    return self.ui.entry1.get_text()
```

This should be placed in the SaveDialog class in the SaveDialog.py file. You can find out about **@property** and its usage [here](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/).